# RealmRecyclerViewAdapter using "modified" dataSet doesn't refresh on Realm change notifications

Tags: android, realm

Suppose I have the following adapter for Transaction class that extends RealmObject.

```
public class TransactionRealmAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Transaction, TransactionRealmAdapter.TViewHolder>
{

    private List<FormattedTransaction> groupedTransactions;

    public TransactionRealmAdapter(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<Transaction> data, boolean autoUpdate) {
        super(data, autoUpdate);
        setHasStableIds(true);
        groupedTransactions = new GroupingHelper().getTransactions(data);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        return getItem(index).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return groupedTransactions.size();
    }

}
```

I perform some processing on transactions when setting up the adapter to get groupedTransactions which is a List of FormattedTransaction class that does not extends RealmObject.

When data changes on a background thread or elsewhere, how do I make sure that my recycleview's UI is updated automatically? I tried re-calculating groupedTransactions in updateData but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Then you need to not use RealmRecyclerViewAdapter, and add the RealmChangeListener which calculates the new List to the RealmResults yourself.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Gabor! Cheers :)